# Flutter Build Image as Map

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a image and I want to use this like Google Maps plugin.

As you can see this image. I want it to stretch to whole screen and able to move it by fingers. I tried Position() widget but couldn't managed to make it work.

[image: Android Simulator]

Here is the code I'm dealing with.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
          backgroundColor: renk,
          leading: Builder(
              builder: (context) => IconButton(
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.info),
                  onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer())),
        ),
        drawer: new Drawer(
          child: Container(color: renk),
        ),
        body: Image.asset('assets/images/kizilbitmis.png'),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
        floatingActionButton: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              FloatingActionButton.extended(
                  backgroundColor: renk,
                  heroTag: "listefalanbruh",
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Liste()));
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.list),
                  label: Text('Kuş Listesi')),
              SizedBox(
                width: 40,
              ),
              FloatingActionButton.extended(
                  backgroundColor: renk,
                  heroTag: "qrcodefalanbruh",
                  onPressed: _scanQR,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.qr_code),
                  label: Text('QR Kod'))
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [InteractiveViewer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrn7V3bMJvg) might solve your ploblem.